# How can I pass parameters to execute() when creating new database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm now learning to use MySQL with python.

When I'm trying to create a new database like this:

```
sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s'
cursor.execute(sql, (self.DB_NAME,))
```

DB_NAME is a string, in this case

```
self.DB_NAME = 'bmagym'
```

I got this error:

```
MySQL Error [1064]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''bmagym'' at line 1
```

But if I replace the code with:

```
sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s' %self.DB_NAME
cursor.execute(sql)
```

It works as expected.

My question is how I can pass parameters to execute() instead of using %?

Comment: Why do you want to pass it with another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database names in the SQL syntax are written like

```
`dbname`
```

SQL accepts plain `dbname` as well.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbname
# works like 
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dbname`
# BUT: only if dbname is not a SQL keyword.
```

The `cursor.execute()` function will automatically format and escape strings (prevent SQL injection). So this query is executed:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'dbname'
```

which is a syntax error. [Here is a similar topic on this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618344/python-mysqldb-and-escaping-table-names) Your second method is fine, just substitute the database name with python `%` operator.

```
sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `%s`' %self.DB_NAME
```